# Remote start/stop of Windows service via System.ServiceController - underlying protocol?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-services

The .NET Framework assembly System.ServiceProcess has a [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class which allows for starting/stopping Windows services on remote machines.

Example:

> ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService", "server123");
>
> sc.Stop();

Which underlying protocols does ServiceController rely on? Does it talk to another service on the remote machine? If yes, on which TCP port does the service on the remote machine listen?

Thanks!

Comment: Ever confirm the port on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but it might be using TCP/UDP port 445 like the NET start/stop command.